# python-pptx: Get row_idx and col_idx values of current cell

Tags: python, powerpoint, python-pptx

I am currently working on a project where I need to locate a cell based on its text content, and then initialise a cell object for the cell immediately to the right of it.

Currently this is my function:

```
from pptx import Presentation

pptx = "path-to-my-pptx"

def update_table():
    prs = Presentation(pptx)
    for slide in prs.slides:
        for shape in slide.shapes:
            if shape.has_table:
                for cell in shape.table.iter_cells():
                    if cell.text == "string-im-looking-for":
                        ### get the current cell's row and col values
                        row = cell.row_idx
                        col = cell.col_idx
                        ### the cell next to it should logically be 
                        next_cell = shape.table.cell(row, col+1)
```

The docs themselves mention a col_idx and row_idx method on the _Cell object here:
https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/table.html#a-few-snippets-that-might-be-handy

However I am getting:
AttributeError: '_Cell' object has no attribute 'row_idx'

Anyone know where I may be going wrong? Or how I could add the row_idx and col_idx methods to the _Cell object in the pptx package's table.py file?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just iterate differently to keep track of those in the loop:

```
for row_idx, row in enumerate(table.rows):
    for col_idx, cell in enumerate(row.cells):
        print("%r is cells[%d][%d]" % (cell, row_idx, col_idx))
```

Comment: That works too, thanks! Great implementation by the way, currently saving me hours of manual work every month!

Do you think the col_idx and row_idx methods should be added nonetheless, so that the example function on https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/table.html#a-few-snippets-that-might-be-handy works?

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind! I found a fix by inserting the following into the tables.py _Cell object (approx. line 184):

```
@property
def row_idx(self):
    return self._tc.row_idx

@property
def col_idx(self):
    return self._tc.col_idx
```

cell x and y coords can now be retrieved by:

```
x = cell.col_idx
y = cell.row_idx
```

Hope this helps somebody else out there!